# React Native Release app error in play console

Tags: react-native, google-play

Enviei minha aplicação para a *Play Store*, porém, no console de erros da loja, apareceram alguns erros depois de alguns downloads. Em meu celular, esse tipo de falha nunca ocorreu

**Erro**:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3334) 
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source) 
>  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1725) 
>  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105) 
>  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164) 
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6694) 
>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) 
>  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240) 
>  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3329)
> ```

**Configuração no Gradle**:

```
rootProject.name = project_name
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-snackbar'
project(':react-native-snackbar').projectDir = new         File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-snackbar/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-text-input-mask'
project(':react-native-text-input-mask').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-text-input-    mask/android')

include ':app'
```

**Configuração no build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

**Configuração no app/build.gradle:**

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-snackbar')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-text-input-mask')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar' 

}
```

Alguém pode me auxiliar a resolver este problema?

Comment: Fiz a tradução, porém não sei se é exatamente o que quis mostrar. Você pode clicar em **[edit]** e corrigi-la.

Comment: Parece muito com um problema Multidex. Acho interessante você dar uma lida em Android [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)